# Verify JWT Claims in WebAPI

Tags: security, asp.net-web-api2, jwt, thinktecture-ident-model

Given the Thinktecture AuthenticationConfiguration below:

```
var authConfig = new AuthenticationConfiguration
{
    EnableSessionToken = true,
    SendWwwAuthenticateResponseHeaders = true,
    RequireSsl = false,
    ClaimsAuthenticationManager = new ClaimsTransformation(),
    SessionToken = new SessionTokenConfiguration
    {
        EndpointAddress = "/api/token",
        SigningKey = CryptoRandom.CreateRandomKey(32),
        DefaultTokenLifetime = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0)
    }
};
```

It would return an example JWT of `eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJzZXNzaW9uIGlzc3VlciIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHA6Ly9zZXNzaW9uLnR0IiwibmJmIjoxNDIwMzk2ODgyLCJleHAiOjE0MjA0MDA0ODIsInVuaXF1ZV9uYW1lIjoicGFzcyIsImF1dGhtZXRob2QiOiJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy5taWNyb3NvZnQuY29tL3dzLzIwMDgvMDYvaWRlbnRpdHkvYXV0aGVudGljYXRpb25tZXRob2QvcGFzc3dvcmQiLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOiIyMDE1LTAxLTA0VDE4OjQxOjA0LjAxOVoiLCJyb2xlIjoiVmVyaWZpZWQifQ.h7curaLrqkMT4Btg-AAoEpNYqUIYNQA_y-eUdEwQBqs`

Which is:

```
{
    "alg": "HS256", 
    "typ": "JWT"
}

{
    "unique_name": "pass", 
    "aud": "http://session.tt", 
    "iss": "session issuer", 
    "authmethod": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/authenticationmethod/password", 
    "role": "Verified", 
    "exp": 1420400482, 
    "auth_time": "2015-01-04T18:41:04.019Z", 
    "nbf": 1420396882
}
```

How would I verify that the JWT was issued from a trusted machine, can we use a symmetric key for the private signing key and the same key on the remote machine to verify against?

How could I wire up the WebAPI so that it automatically does this for us (assuming the AuthenticationConfiguration is on a different machine dedicated to account security api).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a shared symmetric key **or** a private key to sign the JWT and that use that same symmetric key or respectively the associated public key to verify it.

The algorithm in use for this JWT (`HS256`) suggests that a shared symmetric key was used so you need to know that symmetric key at the receiving end in order to verify the JWT.

Comment: Thanks Hans, I updated my question I am using `SigningKey = CryptoRandom.CreateRandomKey(32)` everything else is default with the thinktecture AuthenticationConfiguration library - I know the private key but i cant seem where to find the shared key

Comment: You're generating a random shared symmetric key. You should save that value and send it (probably base64encoded) to the receiver, out of band so he can verify the JWT. There is **no** private key involved in the signing of *this* JWT.

Comment: @HansZ. - do you have any experience using keys with the newest rc1 release of mvc6 ?  If you have a minute please see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34348704/jwtbearer-bearer-token-with-rc-1-update-to-asp-net-5